# Upgrade laravel to version 5.7

Tags: laravel-5

I want to upgrade laravel to 5.7 version. When I type:

```
php artisan --version
```

It shows

```
Laravel Framework 5.4.36
```

In composer.json file I had put

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
    }
```

but version not updating. To update I use:

```
composer update
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Have you deleted your `vendor/` folder and ran `composer update`.

Comment: @thisiskelvin no nothing has been deleted.

Comment: Try and delete the folder (as well as the composer.lock file) and see if it works.